# Get TFS Query Results Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am relatively new to both Powershell and REST API calls. I am trying to get the results of a query in TFS so that I can iterate through the results and compare some data from another application. What I can't figure out is how to get the actual results - I can get the query details just fine, but not the actual results.

```
$TFS_uri = "http://mytfsserver.com:8080/tfs/Company/IT Main/_apis/wit/queries/My Queries/RTB Tactical - Backlog/?api-version=2.0"

#call TFS API
$TFS_responseData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $TFS_uri -Method get -ContentType 'application/json' -UseDefaultCredentials
$TFS_responseData
```

The output gives me the query id (dbfd5177-17af-4265-98c8-bfe19a94b9e3), but I have no idea how to actual execute the query and get the results.

Comment: When discussing on-prem TFS/Azure DevOps Server, please include the version you're using -- it's critical information. That said, the WIQL APIs are what you're after: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-id?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Comment: How do I determine the TFS version? And I’ve tried a WIQL query - I tried “Select ID, Title from WorkItems where ID > 276778”. I got back the id and url for a bunch of records, but not the title. Not sure what I’m doing wrong.

Comment: Here's my attempt at using WIQL - definitely not getting the ID and Title in the results:
$TFS_uri = "http://mytfsserver.com:8080/tfs/Company/IT Main/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=2.0"
$TFS_body = "{'query':'select [system.id],[system.title] from workitems where [system.id] = 274605'}"

$TFS_responseData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $TFS_uri -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -UseDefaultCredentials -Body $TFS_body
$TFS_responseData

#results
workItems       : {@{id=274605; url=https://tfs.hq.mvphealthcare.com/tfs/MVP/13529e7a-425a-4717-8c76-29ae905f05a7/_apis/wit/workItems/274605}}

Comment: It's giving you the URL to the work items that are returned by the query. You can iterate over those and retrieve the work item details with that URL. That's just how the API is designed.

Comment: Got it - figured that was the case. Thanks!